# Getting data from other sources rather than from database in OpenErp

Tags: odoo

I would like to customize OpenERP to get data from other sources rather than from a database and show it in a form.

In my case: 

I have data about employee: name, age, address... which stored in other sources  instead of database.

I don't want to stored it into database but I want to show them in view. Is there any solution and could you give me an advice?
Many thanks

Comment: Please add a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I would suggest creating functional fields and calling out from there. If you make use of the multi option (see the "Performance Optimisation" section of the developer momento) you will only make the external call once.

If you call the fields the same thing, your inherited model will over-write the base field definitions.